# How can we delete a row from MySQL table without using a unique ID?

Tags: mysql

I want to delete a single row from my table and it does not contain any primary key or unique id. How can i do it ?

Comment: Use a where clause that mentions enough of the columns and there values so that only that one row will get selected for delete

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/mysql-query-delete-row-without-primary-key/3342

Comment: Is there a logical key or a unique index?  (a combined group of columns which uniquely identifies a record?)

Comment: Note: The idea with SO is you write it, then we fix it. We are not here to write your code for you

Comment: if i use where clause there are chances that other rows with same value might get affected, since i won't be usiing any unique id

Comment: use a select first to ensure you only get 1 row back then run the delete in a transaction and make sure only 1 row is deleted, if not rollback transaction.  (assuming you can identify enough limiting criteria to get to one record.

Comment: How would you uniquely identify the row you want to delete?  Give the same conditions in the `WHERE` clause.  Or are you trying to delete one of multiple identical rows?

Comment: Thanks everyone. It worked :)

Comment: I think a good question is why does your table not have a unique identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete from sometable where somerow = 'somevalue'
```

!!!! make sure the where statement is a unique identifier or use a mysql editor (for instance heidisql for windows or mysql workbench for linux)

Comment: Since It doesnt have any unique id or pk, it uneditable or read only